# Prevent display to sleep while charging

Tags: charging, screen, sleep

I want to add a functionality option to choose in my android phone so that when the option is selected its display will never sleep when under charging condition.

What should I need to program my software without changing RAM?

Comment: In settings -> device information, tap the build no. a couple of times to unlock the developer mode. Go back to settings and enter developer options, enable it and enable "Don't sleep when charging" (or similar wording).

Answer (score 7):

there is a setting in developer options on your phone that allows you to keep your display awake whilst charging it. It is enabled by going to settings, then scrolling all the way down to about. From there scroll all the way down to build number and tap it 7 times to enable developer mode. Next, click the back button then click on Developer options. Click the tick to turn it on (already on in default). Finally, turn the tick on for Stay awake and your phone will stay awake while charging.